# oauth 2: Javascript vs. PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, oauth-2.0, compare

I want to add "login with XYZ" capability to one of my web apps. I don't need any of the advanced stuff - just logging users in with one of their existing profiles so they don't have to remember yet another login credentials set.

After some research, I found [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) and [hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/).

I know Javascript as well as PHP, but I have never implemented OAUTH 2 support before.

From what I can see, I could technically imagine implementing the identification and authentification both in Javascript or in PHP.

**What would you recommend I choose, and why?**

Comment: Sorry, recommendations and primarily opinion based question are off topic on SO.

Comment: @marekful I am not interested in opinions but in technical reasoning for either one path from people who have implemented oauth 2 before. I don't know yet where the pitfalls of either path could be.

Comment: [oauth2 simplified](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified)

Comment: I would say it depends what you want to choose. @whatout 's answer below is a good start to understand what OAuth says. Once you are confortable with it, you must be able to choose the best for you and your business case

Comment: My suggestion will be choose one that you are familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no comment or answer really answered my question, I'll answer with the additional reading I have been doing. I hope it will help if you arrived here via your research into the same question.

Having to use your "client secret" requires an OAUTH 2 client to have some server-side code (I don't want to have my "secret" in client-side JS, do i...). Hello.js solves this via a [OAUTH Proxy](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy).

Since I prefer to minimize my dependencies on third parties in production, I'd much rather use PHP in the first place.

Therefore, I will be implementing with hybridauth for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had implement some of features like "login with Facebook", here is the common pattern,which is indicated by this picture.[image: example of login with Facebook]

What you have to do is firstly redirecting user to Facebook authentication server and when user get "code" from Facebook authentication server,you can get "access token" by passing "code" to Facebook authentication server(different url). Secondly, when you have "access token", you can now get user profile by Facebook API and then save to database or other thing.

So, the differences between hello.js and HybridAuth is that hell.js uses browser (Javascript) to do things after user redirect with "code", but HybridAuth do it on server side(PHP). But they do have the same pattern which is indicated by the picture.

Comment: Thank you for the friendly summary. I am missing distinct hints at specific differences between JS and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I used both JS and PHP versions for FB.
Using server side library you can do your business without reising suspicions. For example collecting some public info to merge duplicate accounts, storing the profile image, login attempts. Other requests you might need for your business and user experience.